# Como mudar o cursor do mouse

Tags: html5, css3

Estou quereno mudar o cursor do meu mouse coloquei meu código e não funciona a imagens esta em png e não pega eu tenho que usar ela com .cur mesmo se sim como faço isso porque no photoshop por exemplo não possui essa extensão para poder salvar nesse formato

segue o código:

```
body{
    cursor: url(../scroll/mouse.png), default;
}
```

Comment: Na minha resposta, lá na outra pergunta que mencionei, há uma indicação de script Python para converter formato .ico em formato .cur (que eu também precisei utilizar por causa do IE). Se o seu Photoshop salvar em formato .ico, fica fácil. :)

Answer (score 2):

Testei com uma imagem *png* e funcionou certinho no Chrome e Firefox, no IE não.

Você também pode tentar converter esse *png* pra *cur* pelo [Convertio](https://convertio.co/pt/png-cur/).